# How do I get the F9 menu in GNU screen on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shell, gnu-screen

Using `screen` on Mac OSX 10.7.1.

Already applied various hacky fixes to get the home and end keys to work, changed the command key to left control key - however now I find the F buttons all do silly things like make the CD eject or change volume settings.

I've tried stabbing at various combinations with, for instance, the fn key, ctrl, shift etc, but to no avail.

So, is there a specific key combo, or is the F9 menu mapped to something different on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen itself does not have an "f9 menu". I suspect you are meaning the menu added by [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) (previously just called "screen-profiles", see [here](http://linuxaria.com/howto/screen-byobu?lang=en) for a screenshot to see if it is what you are referring to) that adds a number settings and key-bindings (including F9 to get to byobu's configuration menu) to GNU Screen.

Byobu is installed by default by some Ubuntu versions, and is available in the standard repositories of many other Linux distributions, but does not have an "official" package for OSX as far as I know. A quick search finds some tips for getting it installed and working on OSX though, like [this page](http://wamad.engr.sjsu.edu/blog/2011/03/08/installing-byobu-on-os-x-10-510-610-7/).

Comment: *facepalm* yes that's it, I was used to using byobu which is installed on my ubuntu server - colour me embarrased :)

Comment: Nowt to be embarrassed about, sometimes it is setup so `byobu` is used even if you just run `screen` so people might not be aware the other exists so wouldn't know the name/term to search for. It is essentially a set of options and scripts that build on customisation options that exist in `screen`, so there could be other similar tools out there too.

Comment: much appreciated all the same